# What is the maximum number of tags should contain a page that does not significantly slowed down?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, optimization

I need to create a project of web application that contains a very long list of items and I can't use pagination...

How many tags is optimal for the single website from the point of view of the optimization?

When the website begins to slow down due to the large number of tags?

How do you deal in a different way than the pagination?

Can you suggest a javascript library free for commercial use?

Comment: What browser should we consider, what OS, how much memory, which CPU and clock timing...

Comment: When you say you "can't use pagination" - are you talking about server side? client side? what tags does the list of items contains? (is it table/ul/divs)? what is your structure?

Comment: You can use scroll loading

Comment: @gus27: Chrome, Windows/Linux, 4 GB of RAM, i5 4,4 GHz

Comment: @Dekel: both, the structure is arbitrary, I will choose one that will be more favorable. But I prefer an unnumbered list.

Comment: English works much better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @gus27 it all depends on what operating system, browser and most importantly the resources such as CPU and memory that is available to the browser for use.

Having said that, modern browsers can easily handle 100s if not 1000s of tags. The best way to go about optimization is to go make the system and when you hit a bottleneck try to find out the reason for it and then fix it. Don't worry about efficiency until you hit a problem which requires optimization.

Angular.js is the javascript that comes straight to my mind for the kind of javascript library that i think you want.